# Does Django1.3 supports python 2.7.2?

Tags: django, compatibility

I have plans to upgrade my server.My major requirement is python django1.3 and postgres8.4
I am using Django 1.3 and python 2.6.5 currently.Since i want to upgrade the server I want to know whether django 1.3 supports python 2.7.2 ?
I have read the specification that 11.04 comes with python 2.7.1 and 11.10 comes with 2.7.2.

I know that django 1.3 supports 2.4 to 2.7 ? Since i don't want to take any risk on server I want to know whether django 1.3 supports python 2.7.1 or 2.7.2 or both.
Please specify how can i verify i have installed virtual env .I have multiple versions of django and python and they gave the error No module named django.core.management.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using Django 1.3 and Python 2.7.2 at work for quite some time now, and have not faced any compatibility issues.

If you want to have multiple versions of python to be installed, it is better to use tools like pythonbrew (https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew).

Regarding the error "No module named django.core.management", you might have installed django with one of your other versions of python. Again, Better to create virtual envs somewhere in your project directories(so they are easy to find), or Even better to use pythonbrew to manage virtual envs.

Answer (score 3):

Django supports all versions of Python 2.7. Since 2.7.1 and 2.7.2 are minor versions of 2.7, Django will work with them.